# Make an external css file only apply to some HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website updater. My idea is to have certain HTML elements be part of the class **updatable**. I will then change each element with that class to a textarea element. That way it can be updated.

I am dividing the updater.html page into 2 areas; the left side a select element but the right side shows some HTML from the webpage I am updating. **I want all the html on the right side to be affected by a specific css style sheet(the style sheet of the webpage I am updating).** How can I do that?

Because the style sheet is external, I dont want to open the style sheet, read it into memory(is this possible in javascript) then insert it into the iframe that contains the updatable HTML.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="updaterSection">
          <select>
            <option> home </option>
             ...
          </select>
        </td>

        <td class="updatableWebpage">
            <!-- I want all the HTML in this div to be affected by the external css stlyle sheet -->
            <iframe src="/css/specStyle.css">
              <p> uneditable stuff </p>
              <textarea> editable stuff </textarea>
            </iframe>
        </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hum iframe src css? never seen before

Comment: you can use javascript to add a link tag for stylesheets in your iframe html

Comment: "I want all the HTML in this div" — you don't have any divs in your source.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i konw, this is not how you use an iframe,

The inside of the `<iframe>` will be replaced by the page put in the src.

The code you posted is just going to display the css page on your webpage. (a simple example using you code: http://jsfiddle.net/W5ggT/ )
So either you put all the html that is inside your iframe into a new html page which contains a link to the special stylesheet in its header. 
Or you use some ajax to refresh that, but I'm not sure to fully understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the DOM of the html webpage inside your iframe using javascript.
That is only possible if it is in the same domain.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Iframe manipulation</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    // cross browser solution for handling iframe
    var contentProp = (iframe.contentWindow)?iframe.contentWindow.document:iframe.contentDocument;

    var head = contentProp.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.href = "/stylesheet/css.css"; // the new stylesheet to add to iframe
    head.appendChild(link);// adds stylesheet to iframe

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id='iframe' src='test2.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add external.css your css file in the head section (within   tag).

```
 <html>
    <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to the css file">
    </head>

 <body> </body>

</html>



give a different class name to the tag that you want to style. But the style in your external.css     file.

Hope it helps.
```